# Which systemd unit failed at "some time in the past"?

Tags: systemd, logs

I have a monitoring system on my server that indicates that *some* systemd unit did fail at a certain time yesterday.  Now I want to ask `systemctl`/`journalctl` which unit that was and see its logs.

My problem is that a simple `journalctl --since=$the_time` does not show anything about a failed unit.

So how can I list units that were in a failed state at a give time in the past or alternatively how can I list all state changes of all units over time?

Currently I can only retrieve the *current* sate of units with `systmectl status` or `systemctl show`.

Comment: `journalctl --system | grep failed` ?

Comment: Slight variation to @chrisckwong821 with additional filter for systemd :  journalctl  --since="5 days ago" -t systemd | grep -i failed